# Организация отчетности с помощью бд

Tags: sql, алгоритм, jdbc

К примеру, имеется шаблон базы данных с товарами:

- имя товара
- количество определенного вида сырья
- приход этого сырья
- расход
- остаток сырья (после приходов и расходов)

Необходимо создать приложение, в котором можно было бы контролировать приходы и расходы продуктов на складе ежедневно. В силу того, что опыта работы с бд у меня мало, пока предварительно: хочу для каждого нового дня создавать таблицу по шаблону (где в поле "количество" переносились бы значения из поля "остаток" предыдущего дня) + добавить возможность обращаться к созданным таблицам таблицам по дате, чтобы посмотреть данные о сырье на складе за конкретный день.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно привязать дату к конкретной таблице (может создавать таблицы, где она будет выступать именем, или как-то еще), или поправьте меня в моих рассуждениях.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подход не верный. Для реализации описанной задачи достаточно будет две таблицы:

**product** (id, name ...)
**order** (id, product_id, amount, type[IN, OUT], date ...)

И далее, с помощью бизнес логики, делаем все расчеты.

Comment: можно подробнее в беседке?

Comment: Здесь все просто: пришел товар -> записали в order его количество, дату прихода с типом IN. ушел товар -> записали количество, дату с типом OUT. Далее делаем отчет на определенную дату  -> выбираем количество IN  и количество OUT до этой даты ну т.д.

Comment: аааа, кажется, понял. Спасибо большое. гениально)